My formula's desired result is an error, but I want to make it look nicer/cleaner (GoogleSheets)
I'm working with the formula below to determine which values I'm missing compared to another column. Ideally, there will be no values which I'm missing and the result will be #N/A. Unfortunately, this looks messy and broken despite it being the desired outcome.
=FILTER($KM4:$KM23, NOT(COUNTIF(DB4:DB23, $KM4:$KM23)))
I have added conditional formatting with this custom formula to make the text white: =isna(30:30) The error disappears, but there's a tiny red triangle flag that shows there's an error.
How can I add to my formula to make the cell empty or otherwise not an error?


Wrap your whole filter() within ifna()
=ifna(FILTER($KM4:$KM23, NOT(COUNTIF(DB4:DB23, $KM4:$KM23))))


This is great, thank you! I have just added this to my sheet and it works! I have several cells using this formula, however, the issue I have come across is that it doesn't work properly when the cells are empty. Previously, the formula was able to list the missing values even before the column was filled (like a word bank). I suppose there are benefits to that, though!

Do share a test sheet(with perhaps dummy data) to showcase us how you ideally wish to see things happen...
